# how to convert a JSON structure to another and add a extra field in to it

Tags: c#, json

i have json data, which is coming from an API. the structure of json is like this

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "nameid": "s_10",
        "size": "6.46",
        "name": "abc",
        "children": [
            {
                "nameid": "i_101010",
                "size": "8.84",
                "name": "bcd",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "nameid": "si_10101010",
                        "size": "4.00",
                        "name": "efg",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "nameid": "c_3273",
                                "size": 4,
                                "name": "ttt",
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "nameid": "si_10101020",
                        "size": "13.67",
                        "name": "sss",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "nameid": "c_4450",
                                "size": 1,
                                "name": "rrr",
                            },
                            {
                                "nameid": "c_551",

                                "size": 17,
                                "name": "ddd",

                            },
```

i need to convert it to something like the below structure

```
  {
"id": 1,
"parentId": "NULL",
"name": "Root",
"size": 5,
"children": [
{
"id": 10,
"parentId": "1",
"name": "En",
"size": 1,
"children": [
 {
  "id": 1010,
  "parentId": "10",
  "name": "Eee",
  "size": 1,
  "children": [
   {
    "id": 101010,
    "parentId": "1010",
    "name": "Enh",
    "size": 5,
    "children": [
     {
      "id": 10101010,
      "parentId": "101010",
      "name": "Ooo",
      "size": 5
     },
```

so in short, i need to add that field parent id to the first JSON

note: these are partial data, so json may not be a valid one.

Comment: Json isn't XML. There's nothing like XSLT that would allow you to transform one Json version to another. One option is to deserialize the source and map to the target DTOs. Another, is to go through XML and use XSLT for the transformation. Json.NET supports serialization from/to XML. This is shown [here](http://www.bizcoder.com/xslt-is-easy-even-for-transforming-json)

Answer (score 0):

If your source and destination object are Typed Class (e.g. public class **FamilyMembers**)

Automapper is the best way to achieve this.

http://automapper.org/

Let's say your source 'data" is class **Families**. You can map **Families** to **FamilyMembers**

```
//specify source, destination
Mapper.CreateMap<Families, FamilyMembers>(); 

//get source data
Families families = GetFamiliesFromAPI(); 

//map each properties of  families to familymembers
FamilyMembers familymembers = Mapper.Map<Families, FamilyMembers>(families); 

ShowFamilyMembersInDataGrid(familymembers);
```

If you don't want to use Automapper, then go with LINQ

```
Families families = GetFamiliesFromAPI(); 
families.Select(f => f, new FamilyMembers() {name = f.Name, someProperty = f.someProperty }
```

Since you have nested JSON object you need to learn how to handle such as "children" member in your source data and map if via LINQ accordingly