# Map JSON Data from the Web to .NET Class where data varies to each API request

Tags: c#, json, class

I'm making calls to an api from asp.net website using http request. The api returns data in JSON.

> The request is something like this: 
>   GET/stats/{granularity}/{customer_number}/{timestamp_start}/{timestamp_end}.

The problem is that the data returned depends on the timestamps you entered in the request.

This is a sample example:

```
{
    "success": {
        "1310860635": {
            "1396310400": {
                "iPad": 2317357,
                "Other": 564
            },
            "1396915200": {
                "iPad": 2538835,
                "Other": 372
            },
            "1396656000": {
                "iPad": 2349576,
                "Other": 1136
            },
            "1398729600": {
                "iPad": 1648157,
                "Other": 163,
                "HTC Streaming P": 32
            },
            "1397606400": {
                "iPad": 2018706,
                "Other": 788
            },
            "1396396800": {
                "iPad": 2477197,
                "Other": 608,
                "Spider": 2
            },
            "1397692800": {
                "iPad": 2144772,
                "Other": 576
            },
            "1398816000": {
                "iPad": 2117556,
                "Other": 1838,
                "HTC Streaming P": 14
            },
            "1398124800": {
                "iPad": 2662858,
                "Other": 306,
                "Spider": 3
            },
            "1398038400": {
                "iPad": 2658527,
                "Other": 565,
                "HTC Streaming P": 98,
                "Spider": 1
            },
            "1397260800": {
                "iPad": 1696601,
                "Other": 218
            },
            "1396483200": {
                "iPad": 2431192,
                "Other": 204
            },
            "1398297600": {
                "iPad": 2186146,
                "Other": 567
            },
            "1397001600": {
                "iPad": 330815,
                "Other": 32
            },
            "1398211200": {
                "iPad": 2457731,
                "Other": 381
            },
            "1397347200": {
                "iPad": 2037233,
                "Other": 175
            },
            "1397779200": {
                "iPad": 2438668,
                "Other": 445,
                "HTC Streaming P": 40
            },
            "1396569600": {
                "iPad": 517843,
                "Other": 52,
                "Spider": 1
            },
            "1397433600": {
                "iPad": 1517589,
                "Other": 161
            },
            "1398902400": {
                "iPad": 2059013,
                "Other": 1878
            },
            "1397174400": {
                "iPad": 338428,
                "Other": 57
            },
            "1397520000": {
                "iPad": 2024273,
                "Other": 214
            },
            "1397088000": {
                "iPad": 275725,
                "Other": 21
            },
            "1398384000": {
                "iPad": 2511796,
                "Other": 586
            },
            "1397865600": {
                "iPad": 2585367,
                "Other": 613
            },
            "1398470400": {
                "iPad": 2558398,
                "Other": 327
            },
            "1398556800": {
                "iPad": 1447445,
                "Other": 97
            },
            "1398643200": {
                "iPad": 1475406,
                "Other": 161
            },
            "1396742400": {
                "iPad": 2838708,
                "Other": 484
            },
            "1396828800": {
                "iPad": 2502484,
                "Other": 513
            },
            "1397952000": {
                "iPad": 2724871,
                "Other": 371
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to map this json data to a C# class, which should not depend on timestamp which varies on every request?

Comment: There probably is but you'd better clarify in the structure of the JSON response. In the current form, your question does not really make sense.

Comment: ok, then tags like "1397952000" represent the dates between StartDate and EndDate in the request.

Comment: Can you post the Type class of your destination? (e.g. public class IPadClass { public string IPad, public string other  })

Comment: so the structure is:
{"success":
{"customer_name":
{"timestamp":{"iPad":2317357,"Other":564},...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this.

```
public class Products
{
    public string ProductName;
    public int Units;
}
```

Using this class you can serialize like this

```
// available products is your output
Dictionary<string, List<Products>> availableProducts = new Dictionary<string, List<Products>>();

var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic result = serializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(json);

KeyValuePair<string, object> temp = ((Dictionary<string, object>)result["success"]).First();

var customerNumber = temp.Key;
var entries = (Dictionary<string, object>)temp.Value;
foreach (var kvp in entries)
{
    var products = new List<Products>();
    IEnumerable collection = (IEnumerable)kvp.Value;
    foreach (dynamic item in collection)
    {
        products.Add(new Products
        {
            ProductName = item.Key,
            Units = item.Value
        });
    }
    availableProducts[kvp.Key] = products;
}
```

Namespaces used

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

Comment: "the timestamp can be the key which maps to the list of products retrieved" how can i do that?

Comment: is "11310860635" the customer number that you know about previously?

Comment: small change here `Enumerable.First(result["success"]);`

Answer (score 1):

//Just a quick snippets

```
        //Assuming you have this class for your destinationn object
        public class iPadClass
        {
            public string ipad;
            public string other;
        }

        List<iPadClass> ipadList = new List<iPadClass>();

        //since your source is not a typed class
        IEnumerable dataList = getDataFromWebAPI() 

        foreach (var row in dataList)
        {
                ipadList.Add(new iPadClass() { ipad = row[0], other = row[1]});

               //or whichever works for you

                ipadList.Add(new iPadClass() { ipad = row.items[0], other = row.items[1]});
            }
        }
```

Experiments also on using dataList as List instead of IEnumerable

If you want your source to be also a Typed Class  see my answer here regarding such [how to convert a JSON structure to another and add a extra field in to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28042274/how-to-convert-a-json-structure-to-another-and-add-a-extra-field-in-to-it/28042672#28042672)